# Python loop and reassign quantities based on limits

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Community!

I've been stuck on solving a problem for quite a while now. I guess it's a simple error in my for-loop, but I can't seem to locate where it fails.

**What am I trying to accomplish?**

1. Loop through a dataset (from .csv) in format shown below.
2. Assess limits provided in the `# Capacity constraints`-part.
3. For each line in the list of data, check level-category (`level_capacity = {"HIGH": 30, "MED": 100, "LOW": 100}`. The "Level" column contains one of the three as defined with limits in dict `level_capacity`.
4. If the item has not been assigned a week (Column 'Week' Is None), and level_capacity are for the Level of the row, then assign it to `current_week` and write it to column 'Week'.
5. This loop should repeat until all keys in `level_capacities` meet the requirement specified in `level_capacity`.
6. When `level_capacities.values()` == `level_capacity`, increment `current_week` by 1 (moving to next week) and repeat the process.

**What's not working - output**

I'm trying to achieve this, but it seems to be incomplete. Somehow the code stops end breaks the loop when the DateFrame has been fully looped through. My goal is to have it keep looping, until all rows have been assigned a week in column 'Week', and all weeks have maximum quantity (i.e. `level_capacity == level_capacities.values()`

For the sake of keeping the question compressed, below you'll find the first 8 rows of my .csv-file:

```
    Week    Quantity    Level
    1       1           LOW
    19      4           LOW
    39      1           LOW
    4       2           HIGH
    9       18          MED
    12      23          HIGH
    51      11          MED
```

The actual dataset contains 1703 rows of data. I've ran the code, and extracted to Excel to see the distribution:

[image: PivotTable of output]

However, as you can see the distribution does not align with the limits specified above.
Any help would be greatly appriciated!

**Code**

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    # Define capacity constraints
    level_capacity = {"HIGH": 30, "MED": 100, "LOW": 100}
    weekly_capacity = sum(level_capacity.values())
    
    # Init variables
    current_week = 1
    current_weekly_capacity = 0
    level_capacities_met = {"HIGH": False, "MED": False, "LOW": False}
    
    # Load data to DataFrame
    d = {'Week': [1, 19, 39, 4, 9, 12, 51], 'Quantity': [1, 4, 1, 2, 18, 23, 11], 'Level': ['LOW','LOW','LOW','HIGH','MED','HIGH','MED']}
    data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    max_week = data["Week"].max()
    
    while current_week <= max_week:
        for index, row in data.iterrows():
                # Check if the level capacity is met
            if not level_capacities_met.get(row["Level"], False):
                if current_weekly_capacity + row["Quantity"] <= weekly_capacity:
                    # Assign the current week
                    data.at[index, "Week"] = current_week
                    current_weekly_capacity += row["Quantity"]
                    if current_weekly_capacity == weekly_capacity:
                        level_capacities_met[row["Level"]] = True
                else:
                    # Move to next week and reset capacities
                    current_week += 1
                    current_weekly_capacity = 0
            elif current_weekly_capacity + row["Quantity"] <= weekly_capacity:
                # Assign the current week
                data.at[index, "Week"] = current_week
                current_weekly_capacity += row["Quantity"]
    # check if all level capacities are met
        if all(level_capacities_met.values()):
            current_week += 1
            current_weekly_capacity = 0
            level_capacities_met = {"HIGH": False, "MED": False, "LOW": False}
            
    print (data)
```

Comment: Can you add the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My impression is that the code provided in the question has (at least one) error in reasoning and also overcomplicates things.

The main thing is probably that the `current_weekly_capacity` is checked against a total `weekly_capacity`. But this total `weekly_capacity` does not take into account if the capacity of the levels (`HIGH`, `MEDIUM`, `LOW`) is reached.

Think about the following scenario as an (made up) example: You iterate through a data frame. The `weekly_capacity` is not yet reached (say the current value is 100) and also `level_capacities_met = {"HIGH": False, ...}`. The current row has a `Week` value of `None`, a level of `HIGH` and a quantity of `50`. Then the capacity would be happily planned for the current week, even though it exceeds the available capacity for level `HIGH`.

Instead of counting a `current_weekly_capacity` I would suggest counting the capacity of each level separately using `current_weekly_capacities = {"HIGH": 0, "MED": 0, "LOW": 0}` (see also the additional comments in the code).

```py
import pandas as pd
# Define capacity constraints
level_capacity = {"HIGH": 30, "MED": 100, "LOW": 100}
#weekly_capacity = sum(level_capacity.values())  # not required

# Load data to DataFrame    
data = {
        'Week': [1, 19, 39, 4, 9, 12, 51, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 41, 41],
        'Quantity': [1, 4, 1, 2, 18, 23, 11, 1, 10, 8, 10, 5, 3, 1, 40, 2],
        'Level': ["LOW", "LOW", "LOW", "HIGH", "MED", "HIGH", "MED", "HIGH", "LOW", "LOW", "LOW", "HIGH", "HIGH", "HIGH", "HIGH", "HIGH" ]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#df.at["Week"]  = None  # ?? --> replaced by df["Week"] = None (after getting value for max_week)
max_week = df["Week"].max()
df["Week"] = None
```

Check if the sum of `Quantity` for any level and any week exceeds the `level_capacity`:

```py
g = df.groupby(by=['Week', 'Level']).sum().reset_index()
g.rename(columns={'Quantity':'sum'}, inplace=True)
def set_level_capacity(row):
    if row['Level'] == 'HIGH':
        return 30
    if row['Level'] == 'MED':
        return 100
    if row['Level'] == 'LOW':
        return 100
    return -1
g['level_capacity'] = g.apply(lambda row: set_level_capacity(row), axis=1)
print(g[g['sum'] > g['level_capacity']])
```

Now the planning logic (*needs to be revised due to some additional information to the question*):

```py
# Init variables for loop
current_week = 1
current_weekly_capacities = {"HIGH": 0, "MED": 0, "LOW": 0}  #  instead of current_weekly_capacity = 0
level_capacities_met = {"HIGH": False, "MED": False, "LOW": False}  # (1)

while current_week <= max_week:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        # Check if already assigned to a week
        if pd.isna(row["Week"]):
            level = row["Level"]
            # Check if the level capacity is met
            if not level_capacities_met[level]:  # (2)
                if current_weekly_capacities[level] + row["Quantity"] <= level_capacity[level]: # (3) 
                    # Assign the current week
                    df.at[index, "Week"] = current_week
                    current_weekly_capacities[level] += row["Quantity"]  # (4)
                    if current_weekly_capacities[level] == level_capacity[level]:
                        level_capacities_met[level] = True
                        if all(level_capacities_met.values()):  # (5)
                            current_week += 1
                            current_weekly_capacity = 0
                            level_capacities_met = {"HIGH": False, "MED": False, "LOW": False}
                            break
                # removed/not required
                #else:
                #    # Move to next week and reset capacities
                #    current_week += 1
                #    current_weekly_capacity = 0
            # (?? - not required) Level capacities are met but current weekly capacity + row capacity < weekly capacity
            #elif current_weekly_capacity + row["Quantity"] <= weekly_capacity:
            #    # Assign the current week
            #    df.at[index, "Week"] = current_week
            #    current_weekly_capacity += row["Quantity"]
    # (6) moved logic up (see 5) 
    #if all(level_capacities_met.values()):
    #    current_week += 1
    #    current_weekly_capacity = 0
    #    level_capacities_met = {"HIGH": False, "MED": False, "LOW": False}
    # (7) current_week should always be increased after iterating over the complete data frame to avoid an infinite loop
    current_week += 1
    current_weekly_capacities = {"HIGH": 0, "MED": 0, "LOW": 0} 
    level_capacities_met = {"HIGH": False, "MED": False, "LOW": False}
```

(1) I kept the kept the `level_capacities_met`, though the variable is not really required (--> could be replaced by checking if `current_weekly_capacities[level]` of a given level is below the capacity level).

(2) I suggest using `level_capacities_met[level]` instead of the get operator `level_capacities_met.get(level, False)`. This way the code throws an error in case the level is unknown (--> error in database).

(3) Check the capacity of the current level (not a capacity value the summaries all levels).

(4) Add the quantity to the current specific level.

(5) Restart iterating the data frame if all weekly capacities are met

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251332/discussion-between-rosa-b-and-havard-kleven).